# Syntax error at or near 'Except' in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can someone help me find my syntax error? I feel like I've been staring at this stupid section for hours and have tried changing things, rewriting it, etc, but it just keeps giving me an error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.customer_name
FROM depositor AS S
WHERE NOT EXIST (
    (SELECT branch_name
    FROM branch
    WHERE branch_city='Brooklyn')
    EXCEPT
    (SELECT R.branch_name
    FROM depositor AS T, account AS R
    WHERE T.account_number = R.account_number
    AND S.customer_name = T.customer_name));
```

Comment: `EXIST`--> `EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

`EXCEPT` should be between two `SELECT`s, eg

```
SELECT ...
EXCEPT
SELECT ...
```

So your query should be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT S.customer_name
FROM depositor AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT branch_name
    FROM branch
    WHERE branch_city='Brooklyn'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT R.branch_name
    FROM depositor AS T, account AS R
    WHERE T.account_number = R.account_number
    AND S.customer_name = T.customer_name
)
```

I also removed the unnecessary brackets and corrected the spelling error of `EXIST` to `EXISTS`.

Comment: Isn't the `EXCEPT` in the question between two `SELECT`s? I think the only problem is the spelling error in `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thank you! Changing EXIST to EXISTS worked to fix everything!